# VMware snapshot merge vs delete on "DELETE ALL"

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot

A simple version of this question has been asked before (and links to VMware site for simple scenarios exist) - but this is a bit more complicated.  I have 4 snapshot scenarios under VMware esxi 5.5:

[image]

and I want to know what happens when I click "DELETE ALL" snapshots.  Is this correct?

- Scenario 1: A and B will be merged, and there will be NO more
  snapshots
- Scenario 2: B will be thrown away, and there will be NO more
  snapshots
- Scenario 3: A and B will be merged, C will be thrown away, and
  there will be no more snapshots
- Scenario 4: A and B and C will be merged, D
  and E will be thrown away, and there will be no more snapshots.

According to [VMware](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-06CB6D7D-9ECE-4C53-AA11-C5F2662328CD.html), deleting any snapshot merges it into the parent only if it is the current chain.  But I think their article is poorly worded - and it conflicts with other VMware postings that suggest snapshots below the current (you are here) state in the current chain are simply discarded

Answer (score 1):

When you choose "Delete all Snapshots", all of the snapshots go away and you end up with a single disk file.

Comment: Exactly what ewwhite says - you always end up at the 'You are here' stage and all snaps are deleted regardless of scenario.

Comment: What does "GO AWAY" mean?  Some posts say the are merged to the parent (if they are prior to the YOU ARE HERE), others say they are thrown away.  Another posts says all are merged regardless of where YOU ARE HERE is.

Comment: Does it matter? It brings the VM into a consolidated state and removes the snapshots.

Comment: Yes - that's my whole question.  In scenario 2: If changes are thrown away (ie: B is thrown away then I have reverted to state A.  If changes are merged, then I have reverted to state B.  Similarly, in scenario 4, are C and E merged into B, or are E and D thrown away and the disk reverts to state C

Comment: Sorry. I don't know.

Comment: Do you have a specific _problem_? @Telium - Or are these hypothetical?

Comment: @Telium In the time you've taken to ask this question, you could have just tested each scenario and found out for yourself.

Comment: @EEAA - this has been asked so many times on serverfault, and never answered clearly, that a good answer should be usefull to a large number of people.  I don't have permission to experiment with a client system - and setting up an entire VMware test system seemed like overkill for what should have been a straight forward question.

Answer (score -1):

1.First Scenario is last disk are ready in Write mode at B
2.You reverting from last disk and going to First disk data....
3.same like 2 scenario but disk stage is different 
4.scenario 4 is wrong because metedata will not create the new tree...called E ....

I hope you can understand my explanations